# Aligning itemize elements both from left and right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize

I do this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=3cm,labelsep=0.5cm,leftmargin=4cm,align=left}

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}[label=  Example \arabic*:]
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

as you can see **1:** and **2:** are not aligned.

since I use a different font, it has different widths for 1 and 2. How can I align by leftmost letter (E) and :.

So I get something like

```
   Example   1:
   Example  11:
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `\hfill` between `Example` and `\arabic*:`, but you have to adjust `labelwidth` and `labelsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=2.2cm,labelsep=1.3cm,leftmargin=4cm,align=left}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={Example\hfill\arabic*:}]
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]